# Negation of subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Negate If $A \subseteq B$ then $C \subset B$

Is the answer, $A \not \subseteq B \wedge ((C \not \subseteq B) \vee ( C = B))$

Answer (score 1):

No: the negation of "X implies Y" is "X is **true** and Y is false." You've written the negation as, "X is **false** and Y is false." (Do you see why?)

Comment: Yes, I understand! Is the rest correct though?

Comment: @dbz1 Yes, the rest is correct.

Comment: $(x \implies y) \iff (\neg  x \vee y)$
So $\neg(x \implies y) \iff (x \wedge \neg y)$